# Size a window to an image at a URL

Tags: c#, wpf, image

The Source of the `Image` is bound to a URL which points to an image.

If the image at the URL is smaller then the `MaxHeight` and `MaxWidth`, the following code works great.  The image size is exactly the same as the url and the window is sized properly.

If the image at the URL is larger then the `MaxHeight` and `MaxWidth`, only a portion of the image is displayed.  The image does not get shrunk to fit into the window.

If I remove `Stretch="None"`, the large picture then shrinks to fit into the `MaxHeight` and `MaxWidth`, looks great, but the small image gets expanded to consume all available space and looks like crap.

Here are two images I have been testing with:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPS6I.jpg

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.Windows.PictureWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Profile Picture" ResizeMode="NoResize" UseLayoutRounding="True" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" MaxHeight="750" MaxWidth="750">

    <Image Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding}" />

</Window>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this from XAML, but there shouldn't be a problem doing it in the code behind. Download the image, find the size and set the `Stretch` property accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to to remove the Stretch="None", as you say, to make the large image shrink down. But, to avoid the small image to be scaled up, you just add this property:

```
StretchDirection="DownOnly"
```

This prevents small images from being scaled upwards, and allows large images to be scaled down. The Window resizes appropriately as well.

This is the code that I have tested in LinqPad. Just change showLarge to true and false to switch between the images.

```
bool showLarge = false;
var w = new Window();

w.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
w.UseLayoutRounding = true;
w.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
w.MaxHeight = 750;
w.MaxWidth = 750;

Image img = new Image();
img.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
img.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
img.StretchDirection = StretchDirection.DownOnly;
if(showLarge)
    img.Source = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri(@"http://i.imgur.com/iaBp2Fv.jpg"));
else
    img.Source = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri(@"http://i.imgur.com/fiRrTJS.jpg"));

w.Content = img;
w.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind, create a property as

```
public Point ImageSize {get;set}
```

Get the image from the URL in the constructor/Initialize() and set `ImageSize` accordingly

Bind the height and width of your window to `ImageSize.X` and `ImageSize.Y`

```
Height="{Binding ImageSize.Y}" Width="{Binding ImageSize.Y}"
```